# How to apply dynamic TSS in appcelerator with Dynamic TSS Widget

Tags: android, ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

I'm building an app with appcelerator. I want to auto adapt the layout if I have the device in landscape mode or portrait mode.
So after a reserch, I have download a plugin "com.jasonkneen.dynamicTSS" to implement a dynamic TSS.

So this is my code:

```
<View class="container">
        <View id="logoImage" class="images"></View> 
        <Widget src="com.jasonkneen.dynamicTSS"/>

        <Label id="loginLable"
            class="loginLable">Accedi</Label>

        <View id="viewText" class="viewTextLogin">
            <TextField id="username" class="textLogin" hintText="Insert username"></TextField>
            <Widget src="com.jasonkneen.dynamicTSS"/>
            <TextField id="password" class="textLogin" hintText="Insert password" 
            passwordMask="true"></TextField>
            <Widget src="com.jasonkneen.dynamicTSS"/>
        </View>
</View>
```

This is my login.tss file

```
".images":{
    top:"5px",
    backgroundImage : "/images/logo.png",
    landscape: {        
        width : "60%",
        height: "55px"
    },
    portrait: {     
        width : "90%",
        height: "62px"
    }
}

    ".textLogin":{
        top : 20,   
        backgroundColor : "#c9c9c9",
        borderRadius : 10,
        borderWidth : 1,
        borderColor : "#fff",
        color : "#fff", 
        font : {
                fontFamily : 'Roboto-Regular',
                fontSize : "14pt",
                fontWeight : "Regular"
        }, 
        paddingLeft : 10,
        landscape: {        
           height : "30%",
           width: '10%',
        },
        portrait: {     
           height : "12%",
           width: '90%',
        }
    }

    ".viewTextLogin":{
        height:Ti.UI.Fill,
        landscape: {        
           layout:"horizontal"
        },
        portrait: {     
           layout:"vertical"
        }
    }
```

Now The object "logoImage" if I try to change the orientation of my device, is correct. But the view "viewText" if I have the device in portrait mode, I can see that:

[image]

If I turn in landscape mode my device I can see that:

[image]

How can I fixed my problem?

Comment: Not sure what problem you are pointing out...